# SQL where clause CASE switch with multiple THEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are a few EmployeeType in Employee table but categorized as 'Internal' or 'External'. External type is further categorized as 'Contract' or 'Outsource'. I am writing a proc in which I receive a param as @EmployeeType. I am expecting 'Internal' or 'External' or 'ALL' in parameter value.

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EmploymentType = CASE WHEN @EmployeeType = 'Internal' WHEN @EmployeeType = 'External' THEN 'Contract' OR 'Outsource' ELSE EmployeeType END
```

Available EmployeeTypes in table -- Internal, External, Contract, Outsource

After searching a lot on web, I couldn't find a proper syntax to get the desired output. Can anyone please help.

I know its a bad design but its a legacy system and nothing much I can do with it.

Comment: You appear to me missing something here?  If it's `ALL`, that's simple.  If it's `External` you want anything that's `Contract` or `Outsource`.  But what do you want to apply if it's `Internal`?

Comment: If its 'Internal' I want Internal itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you can try this:

```
    DECLARE @EmployeeType VARCHAR(100)='Internal'
    ;WITH EMPLOYEE(ID,EmploymentType)AS
    (
      SELECT 1,'Internal' UNION
      SELECT 2,'Contract' UNION
      SELECT 3,'Outsource'
    )
    SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE 
    WHERE EmploymentType IN (CASE @EmployeeType WHEN 'External' THEN 'Contract' WHEN 'Internal' THEN @EmployeeType ELSE EmploymentType END
                           ,CASE WHEN @EmployeeType = 'External' THEN 'Outsource' ELSE NULL END)
```

--Internal----

```
ID          EmploymentType
----------- --------------
1           Internal
```

------External----------

```
ID          EmploymentType
----------- --------------
2           Contract
3           Outsource
```

-----ALL ----

```
ID          EmploymentType
----------- --------------
1           Internal
2           Contract
3           Outsource
```

Comment: Thanks @Nolan, I have used your idea in last 2 lines without CTE. It works and doesn't have a performance hit as well :)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't even use a `CASE` statement...

```
WHERE
       (@EmployeeType = 'All')
    OR (@EmployeeType = 'Internal' AND EmploymentType = 'Internal')
    OR (@EmployeeType = 'External' AND EmploymentType IN ('External', 'Outsource', 'Contract') )
```

***EDIT:***

That said, no matter how you implement this, you may not get a very good execution plan.  It's in depth, but the reasoning is here: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

`TL;DR` - It's going to be more performant to use `Multiple different queries inside IF blocks` or `Dynamic SQL`.

***EDIT:***

If you want to do this with a `CASE` statement, or it's an academic exercise in how this *type* of thing should be phrased...

In SQL Server, the `CASE` statement can only return a scalar value.  It can't return a list, or even a Boolean result.  This forces you to something with nested conditions.

```
WHERE
  CASE @EmployeeType
    WHEN 'All'
      THEN 1
    WHEN 'Internal'
      THEN CASE WHEN EmploymentType = 'Internal' THEN 1 END
    WHEN 'External'
      THEN CASE WHEN EmploymentType IN ('External', 'Outsource', 'Contract') THEN 1 END
  END
  =
  1
```

Which isn't very pretty.

Another option would be to use a sub-query that can return a set of values to compare against.

```
WHERE
    EmploymentType IN (
        (
            SELECT 'Internal'  AS type WHERE @EmployeeType IN ('All', 'Internal')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'External'  AS type WHERE @EmployeeType IN ('All', 'External')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Contract'  AS type WHERE @EmployeeType IN ('All', 'External')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Outsource' AS type WHERE @EmployeeType IN ('All', 'External')
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do anything for 'Internal' and 'All' if not then just a If statement should suffice as below
IF (@EmployeeType = 'External')
BEGIN
//Write your logic here.

END